Microsoft Trusted Signing - Powershell (Untrusted Publisher)
We've subscribed to the new Microsoft Trusted Signing service here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/trusted-signing/overview
We've then used the documentation provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/trusted-signing/overview to sign a .PS1 file. This does correctly sign the file however when I run the script on a machine with and execution policy of AllSigned, I get the trusted publisher error:
File C:\Users\Username\OneDrive - COMPANY\Desktop\test.ps1 is published by CN=<COMPANY NAME>, O=<COMPANY>, L=Leeds, S=Leeds,
C=GB and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"): N

Could someone tell me if the Trusted signing service is actually capable/meant to be used for signing powershell scripts? I'd of thought it should have been but I could be wrong.
The root CA on the certification path is in my trusted root certification authorities when I check in the certificate manager on the machine. However the intermediaries between the company certificate and the root are not. Is there something else I need for this to be trusted by powershell?
Please see a screenshot of the cert path details below:

I appreciate this is a very new service but any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit to show a screenshot of the digital signatures tab on the script in question:


What is shown under the context menu ->  Properties -> Digital Signatures (tab) of the concerned PowerShell (test.ps1) file?

It shows an embedded signature with the Name of signer being our company name, digest algorithm is sha256 & Timestamp is 2nd October 2024 11:31:26. I've added a screenshot of that.

To suppress the prompt, you need both the the root cert in your root CA store and the signing cert itself in your Trusted Publishers store. If the root is not trusted, then running the script just fails instead of prompting the user (depending on execution policy).

@Cpt.Whale When using MS trusted signing, the validity period of the certificate applied to the signed file is only 3 days and the certificate is re-issued everyt time you sign a new file. This would hint that Trusted signing isn't really an option for signing powershell files would you say?
When signing with an EV Public Code Signing cert from a well recognised vendor, is it the same requirement? Surely for third party software vendors providing PS scripts this would cause issues too?

@AlexCarter For validity, the digital signature in a script is valid until the signing certificate expires or as long as a timestamp server can verify that the script was signed while the signing certificate was valid (shows up as a countersignature in the signature details). For example, add -TimestampServer http://timestamp.sectigo.com to your signing command

@AlexCarter and yes, the requirement is the same for publicly-trusted certs if you're using the "AllSigned" execution policy. Even Microsoft's own modules will prompt the user to trust the publisher (often multiple times if they used more than one signing cert). Execution policy is really meant for interactive use, where the user has to approve each publisher. I'd recommend using "RemoteSigned" (the default for windows server OS), and use a trusted PSRepository for distribution

@Cpt.Whale sorry I've been away on holiday so haven't had a chance to reply. We will be making use of powershell remediation scripts in InTune, is there a requirement for these to be signed by a trusted publisher or can we use unsigned scripts for remediation purposes (if we use the RemoteSigned option for execution policy)?

Only if you enable Enforce script signature check on the script package. Powershell scripts built into the Remediation itself get automatically signed and trusted by the clients. 3rd-party scripts require manual signature, cert added to client trusted publishers, and adjusted execution policy (since clients default to Restricted). It's nicely documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/remediations#script-requirements . The RemoteSigned policy shouldn't care since those scripts won't be tagged as remote (downloaded from internet)

OK so based on this documentation, for third party scripts, we could just disable the Enforce script signature check on the script package and it should just run as expected without the execution policy getting in the way or the trusted publishers prompt?

Correct, it looks like the remediation scripts only use the device's execution policy if you enable that setting.
